# why func() and func(void) are different

Tags: c, function

I have a function, can write in 2 ways.

```
void function(void) {
        // operations....
}
```

and

```
void function() {
       // operations......
}
```

Both functions are of same prototype. Why we have to mention `void` as argument at function definition?

Comment: some compilers need `void` to be there to understand it.

Comment: @Pazis: Some? All compilers that strictly adhere to the C standard should.

Comment: @JEM: `void func()` is *not* a prototype at all. So your assertion that "both functions are of same prototype" is simply false.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, both have different prototypes.

Compile the below programs you will understand.

```
void function1(void)
{
   printf("In function1\n");
}

void function2()
{
   printf("In function2\n");
}

int main()
{
   function1();
   function2(100); //Won't produce any error
   return 0;
}
```

Program 2:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 void function1(void)
 {
    printf("In function1\n");
 }

 void function2()
 {
    printf("In function2\n");
 }

int main()
{
    function1(100);   //produces an error
    function2();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to say "no parameters" in C and C++ is

```
void function(void);
```

But when we write

```
void function();
```

It means a little different way in C and C++! It means "could take any number of parameters of unknown types", and in C++ it means the same as **function(void)**.